# Mouse Clicks on a Cloud VM?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, virtual-machine, robotjs

I have a NodeJS application that uses Selenium and RobotJS to do some browser automation. Specifically, RobotJS is used to perfom clicks on the browser (Chrome) context menu. Running this application on my computer would interfere with my usage of the mouse and consequently prevent me from doing other tasks while this application is running.

As per my knowledge, it is not possible to automate interaction with the context menu in any way other than this. My question is: How would this application work on a Cloud VM? Would it still use my mouse (because I'm running the VM from my computer)? If yes, what could be a potential solution involving VMs that doesn't involve my mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I´m pretty shure that you can archieve this in a VM but if you really want to free you mouse use you dont even need to do that.
What i recommend is **Headless Browsing**, you may wanna consider running browser in headless mode. This means the browser runs without a graphical interface, which can be useful for automated tasks. Selenium supports headless browsing, and you can interact with elements using JavaScript without the need for mouse clicks.